Synchronizing multiple ECUs
Say I have an ECU that controls the exterior LED lighting of a building, for aesthetic purposes. Due to the size of the building and the amount of LED strips needed, multiple ECUs are needed, each controlling a section of the lighting. All these ECUs periodically receive multicast frames on their Ethernet port regarding the settings for the lighting color and brightness.
How do I make sure that, when one of the settings changes, e.g set a new color, all the ECUs receive and process the data and change the lighting at visually the same time?

What protocol are you using to control the ecus, and how precisely simultaneous do you need?

I am thinking of using EtherNet/IP (CIP), but I am open to a different protocol if it makes the job easier. The timing difference shouldn't be detectable by human eyes.

but then "reacting correctly and reliably to commands coming in via a protocol" is simply up to your correct implementation of said protocol. (of course, you need to deliver the commands to all affected machines, but for ethernet, that seems like a solved problem; use network switches and set up your network correctly). If this is just for decorative / safety/ workspace lighting, the microseconds to milliseconds of latency between different microcontrollers won't be perceptible.

"same time" is impossible. Please define your max allowed time difference.

Have you looked at existing protocols for controlling lighting like KNXnet or ArtNet? Is there a reason you aren't at least starting with an existing standard?

Do you have access to the software/firmware of the ECUs?  IMHO, I have seen boards with outboard IC's like comparators that can have interrupt ( strobe ) inputs. But that would likely be sloppy. But software for whatever CPU is in there should allow for an interrupt.
